# ArrayCollection extend error

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop

i extend ArrayCollection class for add push method

```
package com.cargo.collections
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class DataCollection extends ArrayCollection {

        public function DataCollection(source:Array = null) {
            super(source);
        }

        public function push(...parameters):uint {
            var i:uint = source.push(parameters);
            this.refresh();
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

but pushed data is array :/

```
var test:DataCollection = new DataCollection({id: 1});
test.source.push({id: 2});
test.push({id: 3});
```

output is

```
test = Array( {id: 1}, {id: 2}, Array({id: 3}) )
```

Comment: Why is this output wrong?  What exactly were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `...parameters` creates an array containing all the arguments passed to that function. This should work as expected:

```
public function push(...parameters):uint {
    var i:uint = source.push(parameters[0]);
    this.refresh();
    return i;
}
```

Alternatively, if your purpose is to enable the pushing of multiple parameters you can use the Function.apply() method, which will translate a given array into multiple parameters:

```
public function push(...parameters):uint {
    var i:uint = source.push.apply(null,parameters);
    this.refresh();
    return i;
}
```

This is the equivalent of saying

```
var i:uint = source.push(parameters[0],parameters[1],parameters[2]);  // etc
```